# Eclipse - Android 10 SDK not compatible with Mac OSX

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I am trying to load an old project that requires Android sdk 10. However, when I am trying to download the SDK in `Android SDK Manager` the SDK Platform status shows `Not compatible with Mac OSX`.

[image]

On my other mac I have this installed.

What is going wrong?

I have tried both eclipse Luna and eclipse Mars2

Comment: This is why I said "#$@&^% you Eclipse" and moved on to Android Studio. Eclipse is no longer fully supported by Google, so whole lotta stupid things started happening. For me Android Studio runs absolutely smoothly.

Comment: I was trying to import my project in Android Studio.. But the process is way to crazy I get hundred of errors

Comment: That can mean two things: 1) Your project is in bad need of fixing (Android Studio has much much better (potential) error/problem detection), 2) You did not fully read and follow guide lines that Android Studio provides. I imported more than 100 Eclipse projetcs to Android Studio with no issues.

Comment: where can I find the correct guidelines?

Comment: Is it really hard to use Google (search "Migrate Eclipse project to Android Studio" for example)? And also you get guide lines and potential ways to fix errors during the import process in Android Studio.

Comment: @SlobodanAntonijević Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio didn't work for me neither. And neither for any of our developers that moved to Android Studio... We now always create the structure from scratch again and then just copy the code otherwise it never worked out. Tried it with 1.5, 2.0 and 2.1 and everywhere the same problem ;). So either you're lucky or your projects are dead simple and thus there are no migration problems for you, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face same issue, after a day of research I found out solution to run lower api in eclipse which are not compatible.

You can download the platform from this link
 http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html or from another way.

create a folder android-10 in your sdk/platform folder and copy all the content of downloaded folder into android-10, then start eclipse. Then you can download image file from sdk manager itself.